# The application “Some.app” can’t be opened. Error after creating with py2App

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I created an OSX Something.app using py2app. The app worked great on my computer but then failed when I moved it over to my other computer where I got the warning
`The application “CleanScraper” can’t be opened.`

The whole point for me packaging my python script up as an app was so I could transfer it easily between machines without having to install all the needed modules each time.

I used Google Drive to try the app on both computers. I also found that when I built a fresh version with py2app on the other machine it worked on that one, but not the first machine.

Is there a trick to making py2app apps transferable between machines? Does the app 'know' its home machine somehow?

Comment: Google Drive probably didn't copy the executable file permissions. An internet search for your error should have explained this. From SuperUser: [The application “SomeApp.app” can’t be opened](https://superuser.com/questions/898124/the-application-someapp-app-can-t-be-opened)

Comment: So would copying it using a flash drive be different? I've tried the methods detailed in that question.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure if OS X will preserve the permissions on certain drive formats like FAT32 which do not natively support them. A DMG or a ZIP could also work.